# Delete log data from Elasticsearch that is older than 1 day automatically using crontab

Tags: php, elasticsearch, cron, delete-file

Due to a lot of log data coming into my small server I would like to delete Elasticsearch log data every day using crontab. I have done so many researches on the Internet and have found the solution using curator or Elasticsearch _ttl. But nothing works for me. Now I have no clue any more how to google or what to google. Because I have tried many things what I have found on Google but nothing works. So please help me with a clear instruction.

Comment: how you are indexing logs in ES?? using river or your code??

Comment: I use Logstash to send log data to ES. I have tried your CURL but I get an error.

Comment: I just tried your curl code again to get the error and answer your question but this time it does not return an error but insert one log line into Elasticsearch. Elasticsearch on my server receives data from Logstash. How can I use such CURL?

Comment: Is there another solution besides using CURL?

Comment: Provide information like  index name,logstash config,index type..

Comment: input {
  file {
    type => "apache-access"
    path => "/var/log/apache2/access.log"
  }

  file {
    type => "apache-error"
    path => "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
  }
}


output {
  stdout { }
  elasticsearch_http {
    host => "192.168.1.200"
    index => "logstash-test"
  }
}

Comment: I have different indexes and types, not a specific one.

Comment: i cant find your previous question..post the answer that i posted for your previous question..

Answer (score 4):

[Elasticsearch Curator](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/current/index.html) can only delete indices, not individual documents stored in indices.

If you are trying to delete indices, and your index names meet the expected criteria, then Curator will do the job.

Curator expects indices to have a prefix and a time string.  For example `--prefix logstash- --timestring %Y.%m.%d` would match an index named `logstash-2014.07.30`

A Curator command to delete indices matching these criteria:

- Connect to elasticsearch host `es-host`
- time unit of `days`
- indices older than 1 `time-unit`
- a prefix of `prod-`
- a time string year.month.day (`%Y.%m.%d`) might look like this:

`curator --host es-host delete indices --older-than 1 --time-unit days --prefix prod- --timestring %Y.%m.%d`

TTL is for letting Elasticsearch delete documents after they have lived a given time.  This is problematic for logging use-cases for the same reasons that a million SQL statements like `delete from TABLE where datestamp < 2014.06.01` is more costly than dropping a partitioned table, e.g. `drop table DATA-2014.05`.  There is a lot of disk I/O involved, and it can hurt performance.  If you are not continuously indexing hundreds (or more) documents per second, then TTLs may still be a good fit for you.  See more about that [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-ttl-field.html).